# how can I realize something like this in CSS ans HTML?

Tags: css, html

how can I realize something like this in CSS ans HTML ?

```
 <bod>     
 <div id="corner">    
 <div id"link_img"></div>  
 <div id "link_text">LINK</div> 
 <div> 
 <bod>
```

http://img7.imageshack.us/my.php?image=linke.jpg

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to support both types of markup, HTML and BBCode?

Comment: sorry is my first question.
try it now pls.
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (if you can't change the tags but can add an `&nbsp;` in

```
 <div id="corner">    
     <div id="link_img">&nbsp;</div>  
     <div id="link_text">LINK</div> 
 <div> 

<style type="text/css">

#link_img {float: left; width: 20px; background-color: #ffff00; margin-right: 5px;}
#link_text {float: left; color: #ffff00;}

</style>
```

If you can't add the `&nbsp;` you'll need `height: 20px;` on `#link_img`

Alternatively something like this:

```
<div id="link_text">LINK</div> 

<style type="text/css">

#link_text {color: #ffff00; border-left: 20px solid #ffff00; padding-left: 5px;}

</style>
```